# Finding average of elements with the previous elements and summing it and averaging

Tags: python, math

I have a set of numbers, just to make it easier:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...])
```

I want to:

```
((0+1)/2 + (2+1)/2)/2 , ((1+2)/2 + (3+2)/2)/2, ....
```

I am not sure how to go about this.  What I got so far:

```
B = (A[1:]+A[:-1])/2.0
```

I would expect to get:

```
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...]
```

Any help would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: Please confirm: do you want to calculate `((a0+a1)/2 + (a1+a2)/2 + (a2+a3)/2 + ... (an-1+an)/2)/n`? Of so, it is equivalent to `(A.sum()-A[0]/2-A[-1]/2)/A.size`.

Comment: What is your expected output? Not in formulas, but in values?

Comment: @DYZ, that is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: @RafaelC, I would get `[1,2,3,4...]`

Answer (score 1):

```
>> import numpy as np
>> def pair_avg(a):
>>    return (a[1:]+a[:-1])/2.0
>>
>> a = np.arange(10)
>> pair_avg(pair_avg(a))
array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.])
```

pair_avg does a running average of every pair in a.
As I understand you want to do this twice. I think you should see this operation as a recursive application of the same function. If you always want to recurse twice, you can do

```
>> def oper(a):
>>    b = (a[1:]+a[:-1])/2.0
>>    return (b[1:]+b[:-1])/2.0
>>
>> oper(a)
array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.])
```

Of course, this is equivalent to some weighted sum of the original array elements. Every 2nd application of `pair_avg` will just clip off two more end point values of the original array when you apply it to integers.

Comment: The second one is what the OP asked for (a running mean), the first solution gives a different result and it's quite complicated... I'd leave just the second part...

Comment: OP asked for a recursive application of the running mean as I understood. `pair_avg(pair_avg(a))`. But yes, second definition of `pair_avg` is better and I will edit

Comment: After the OP edit, I agree with you that they want a two-pass moving average